# How to copy text from txt file and paste into xlsx file in node environment using xlsx library

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, text, cypress

I have cast names from my cypress test and I have saved them in a text file named 'name.txt' which is in my project root directory. I want to copy all the text from my 'name.txt' file and paste it in excel file 'qaautomation.xlsx' sheet 'Series Cast' and column 'Name'. I want to write the code in cypress/plugins/index.js for copying the text from name.txt file to 'qaautomation.xlsx' file using xlsx library. But I have no idea how to copy text from excel file and paste in particular sheet and particular column of excel file

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First install the XLXS library in your editor.

```
npm install xlsx
```

And then read your .txt file with `XLSX.readFile() and append the data of text file to excel sheet. You can obviously create the custom column.

```
if(typeof require !== 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');

const file = `scripts/output.xls`;
const txt = XLSX.readFile('scripts/input.txt');
XLSX.writeFile(txt, "scripts/output.xls")
```